# Here I use the condition of dated if & want to multiply the result in the same cell

Tags: excel-formula

Problem on if condition

```
=if(date>fixed date, DATEDIF(fixed date,date,"MD"),IF(result>0,(value*3%)*result,0))
```

the output is not satisfying. What would be the best possible solution. So that as a fresher i can apply it on my google sheets

Comment: What is `3%`? Shouldn't that be `3/100`?

Comment: What's not satisfying about the output?

Comment: Can you explain where Result & value come from? Is this supposed to be the result of the datedif formula?